# android.view.InflateException on setContentView layout containing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

While making my app I realized that I used a fragment class instead of an activity, but instead of restarting I made a new XML layout file and put it in a fragment component instead. Now when I call setContentView on that layout my app crashes, is there a way I can use this fragment class still or do I need to restart with an Activity class?

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.redacted.redacted.ui.pSelect.pSelect"
        tools:layout="@layout/p_select"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Any help at all is appreciated.

p_select:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res      /android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Selection Page"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/title"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:id="@+id/select_RV"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/select_RV">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="id 1"
    android:onClick="button1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="id 2"
    android:onClick="button2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="id 3"
    android:onClick="button3"/>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the error message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.redacted.pnews, PID: 10863
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.redacted.pnews:layout/p_fragment: Binary XML file line #8 in com.redacted.pnews:layout/p_fragment: Error inflating class fragment
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.redacted.pnews:layout/p_fragment: Error inflating class fragment
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.redacted.pnews.ui.pSelect.pSelect
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3717)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.redacted.pnews.MainActivity.backBTN(MainActivity.java:91)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

I would rather not post the class code for personal reasons

The onCreateView is called within an onclick listener in the MainActivity class, and the primary use of the fragment class is to fill in the recyclerview in p_select, so I dont the fragment class code affects this error.

Comment: can you post @layout/p_select this layout code?

Comment: what error should be accure and so what you have done for this ?

Comment: post the class code and logcat error screen

Comment: Kindly post your activity code and fragment path.
Yes it should work

Comment: Ive added new information

Answer (score 1):

The error message says

> Error inflating class fragment Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: **Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id** for com.redacted.pnews.ui.pSelect.pSelect

So add an `android:id` to your `<fragment>`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/select_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.redacted.redacted.ui.pSelect.pSelect"
    tools:layout="@layout/p_select"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't work, but that specific error line is gone now

Comment: I mean, that *does* mean it fixed your problem. It would not have worked without this change, as having an id or tag is required. You just found other unrelated issues after you fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an error within the class I made, thanks for the help but it seems the answer is unrelated to the question.